# Java how to output unreadable binary file

Tags: java, file, text, io, binary

I would like to output text as a unreadable(human) binary file. For example if i open a image file with notepad it brings strange characters up, how would i create a file like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those unreadable characters are just ascii values that don't have a visual meaning so to speak. Have a look at http://www.asciitable.com/.

You could use the ascii values above 128 and below 255 and they will appear as those symbols denoted in that website. Although if you said what exactly it is that you are trying to create, then maybe we could help you better.

Comment: Thanks. Im just wanting to create some user/password files that humans cant read.

Comment: when you say user/password files, are you saying that you are trying to store the username and passwords in a file?